# Moving partial data from one row to another row in same sheet by inserting new row just below

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically what I am looking for is if I have data in column 9 of each row, I want to split that row into two rows. I do not want to scroll through to see the entire data. If column 9 has data, then cut the data from  column 9 to the last column and insert a row below to paste that cut data. I have written a piece of code, but it isn't working.

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = ss.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues();
var getRow  = rangeData.getRow()

for (var i = 0; i <= lastRow; i++) { 

   var row = data[i];
   Logger.log('data row ' + row);
   var rangeToMove = ss.getRange(/*startRow*/ i, /*startColumn*/ 9, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ ss.getMaxColumns());
   ss.insertRowAfter(i);
   rangeToMove.moveTo(ss.getRange(i++,2,2,9));


}
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to split the rows in nine columns chunks, writing the row surplus immediately under the original row. If my understanding is correct, the following code will work for your scenario. I saw in your code that you don't want to interact with the first row; I respected that decision in my code.

```js
function so61670015() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastColumn = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var rawData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastColumn).getValues();
  var maxColumn = 9; // Column I
  var data = [];

  // Step I - Clean
  for (var j = 0; j < rawData.length; j++) {
    data.push(rawData[j].filter(value => value != ""));
  }

  // Step II - Wrap
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[j].length > maxColumn) {
      var surplus = data[j].slice(9);
      data[j].splice(9);
      data.splice(j + 1, 0, surplus);
    }
  }

  // Step III - Fill
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[j].length < maxColumn) {
      var emptyColumns = maxColumn - data[j].length;
      for (var s = 0; s < emptyColumns; s++) {
        data[j].push("");
      }
    }
  }

  // Step IV - Overwrite
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValue("");
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, 9).setValues(data);
}
```

I commented on the different sections of the code to make it clearer. In the initial step I declared all the variables that will be needed later. This part of the code uses the same [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) methods as your original code.

In the first step the code will clean all the void values of the data (void as in `""`, not `null`). This will help to differentiate empty cells from filled ones. I used the method [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to write in the array `data` only the non-void values.

Then the code will cut every row at the maximum column size (column I in your question) and write the row surplus in a new row below. The code performs that action with the methods [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) (to read and modify the array respectively). Please, note how I use `.splice()` twice: first to modify the row by removing every cell over the column limit, and later to modify the data array to insert a row with the surplus cells. If the surplus is still longer than the maximum allowed, then it will repeat the operation until all rows adhere to the column limit.

After those procedures, the data need to be filled again with void values (as in `""`) in those rows that ended up being smaller than the column limit. This action will be required to write the data later, because the method [`.setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) requires the array of values being of equal size of the selected [range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range). To accomplish that I used the [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to insert void values in every row until the column limit is reached.

Finally the data is ready to be written. In a two steps process, the code will first clear the original sheet and write the final data immediately after. This marks the end of the operation.

To illustrate the usage of this code, if we use the following sample data:

[image: Original sheet]

We will end up with this sheet:

[image: Final sheet]

Please, ask me any question if you need further help or clarifications.